# I can't log on to a page using curl

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I need to log on a page using curl to get a value from the page, but I don't get any result at all.
Have I missed something or is it maybe impossible to implement?

```
<?
$u = "******************";
$p = "******************";

$token = file_get_contents("https://secure.izettle.com/portal/login");
preg_match('/content=\"(.*?)\" name=\"csrf-token/', $token, $t);
$authenticity_token = $t[1];
echo $authenticity_token;

$fields = array("user[email_address]" => $u, "user[password]" => $p, "authenticity_token" => $authenticity_token );
$ch = curl_init();

//Set curl options
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://secure.izettle.com/portal/login",
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => "cookie.txt",
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => "cookie.txt",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields
);

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://secure.izettle.com/portal/reports?date=2014-05-21");
$page = curl_exec($ch);

if(!curl_exec($ch)){
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
}

echo $page.'<br>';
```

Comment: So what is `$page` printing?

Comment: Nothing at all .. white page

Comment: I have just looked at the request when you try to login, seems that they pass an `authenticity_token`. You should probably first request the main page to get that token

Comment: So i grabbed the authenticity_token and put it in the $fields but that did not help. I've changed my code above as well

Comment: check for error using `curl_error()`

Comment: Warning: curl_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible for split up the code and try. Not sure it will work. Assumes the second form method is "post"

```
<?php
        $u = "******************";
        $p = "******************";

        $fields = array("user[email_address]" => $u, "user[password]" => $p);
        $ch = curl_init();

        //Set curl options
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://secure.izettle.com/portal/login",
            CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => "cookie.txt",
            CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => "cookie.txt",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION =>true


        );

        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        unset($ch);

        //***************************************************************************** 

        $qry_str = "?date=2014-05-21";


         $ch = curl_init();

    // Set query data here with the URL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'secure.izettle.com/portal/…' . $qry_str);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '3');
    $content = trim(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($content);
        ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get a completly white screen

Comment: can you comment the portions after //*******************  and run the script

Comment: Got the message wrong email and password and this last attempt I know i had wrong password and maybee I tryed to many times so my account is blocked right now. I'll be back asap. THANK YOU VERY MUCH SO FAR!

Comment: Password reseted and now correct entered.
Now I get the message: You are being redirected.
That must means I'm correct logged in though it complained first

Comment: No, it does not I'm afraid. I can't get any further then tis screen comment "You are being redirected"

Comment: remove the comment in the code, try run the above code

Comment: I did, but there were no change

Comment: Thanks, but it did not help. (white page). If I log in normaly the landing page is: https://secure.izettle.com/portal/dashboard but I have tryed with that as well in the 2:d part curl width no luck

Comment: what is be exact url that is getting the report when you post the date value?

Comment: Exactly as in the code: https://secure.izettle.com/portal/reports?date=2014-05-21

Comment: what is the type of request is it a GET or POST method?

Comment: POST ...... <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/portal/login" class="login-form large-fields" data-jortal-logout="https://secure.izettle.com/logout" id="new_user" method="post">

Comment: no i am talking about the report page https://secure.izettle.com/portal/reports?date=2014-05-21

Comment: I can't se that as it is not my page. I do not own the script, but as it only links on the page to choose date i guess it must be GET (right?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54266/discussion-between-fortune-and-user3214817).

Comment: Just for completeness: this won't work anymore, because the login now utilizes recaptcha.